# There was a problem assigning values ​to the new column by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column with pandas that has a string value based on col1 and col2. So, if the value in col1 is greater than or equal to 4 and if col2 value is greater than or equal to 4 then add 'high' to col3 in the same row. Like this

[image]

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [4, 5, 6, 7, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
for item in df.values:
    if item[0] >=4 and item[1] >=4: df['col3'] = 'High'
    else: df['col3'] = 'Low'
```

But now the df values ​​are like this:

```
    col1   col2  col3
0     1     4    Low
1     2     5    Low
2     3     6    Low
3     4     7    Low
4     5     2    Low
```

How is it possible for all values ​​to be low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect:

```
for item in df.values:
    if item[0] >=4 and item[1] >=4: df['col3'] = 'High'
    else: df['col3'] = 'Low'
```

You modify the **entire** `col3` column at every iteration. Effectively the last item will decide how the entire column looks like.

Try with `min()` and comparison:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df[['col1','col2']].min(1) >=4, 'High', 'Low')
```

Or since you have only two columns, you can compare directly:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col1'].ge(4) & df['col2'].ge(4), 'High', 'Low')
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4   Low
1     2     5   Low
2     3     6   Low
3     4     7  High
4     5     2   Low
```

Comment: or also `df['col3'] = np.where(df[['col1','col2']].ge(4).all(1),"High","Low")`

Comment: I can't even beat this guy to the comments ;-)

Comment: @QuangHoang  Can you tell me what they do .min() and .get() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda functions for that:

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'High' if row['col1'] >=4 and row['col2'] >=4 else 'Low' ,axis=1)

#Output: 

   col1 col2 col3
0   1   4    Low
1   2   5    Low
2   3   6    Low
3   4   7    High
4   5   2    Low
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting the entire column to 'low' or 'high' when you update the values, rather than just a single row in the column. The correct way to do this would be to create an array and then add it to the array like so:

```
array = []
for item in df.values:
    if item[0] >=4 and item[1] >=4: array.append('High')
    else: array.append('Low')

df['col3'] = array
```